# Redirect if $s is invalid

Tags: php, html, ajax, redirect, header

This is code from ajax script, after computing through all the necessary conditions $n and $view are created and displayed with the following code

```
<?php
//ajax conditions
?>
<data>
<handler value="show_view"/>
<item id="view<?php echo $n;?>" 
value="<?php echo rawurlencode($view);
        if (strpos($s,'invalid') !== false) 
        {
         echo "Hit Invalid";
         $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
         header( "Location: $url" ); //<--not working   
         exit;
        }
      ?>"/>
<item id="end" value=""/>
</data>
```

I have $s in script..all i want to do is redirect script if the variable $s in invalid..script works fine but redirect doesn't work.
Please suggest some solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should get JavaScript to do the redirect, what you have won't work as you have already sent headers out so you can not send out the location header.   
Either have the location header output first or add javascript to do the redirect to $url

Comment: Probably because you're already in the middle of the document (body) while trying to set headers? Can you please add what errors you get? Btw.: I'm sure this is a duplicate - there must be similar questions already.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the header where you have the conditions at the very top? for the location [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) it needs to be outputted first before anything else.

Since i am unsure what your trying to accomplish with adding stuff to `value="`  if you just want a quick redirect you could just hand it over to javascript to do.

```
value="<?php echo rawurlencode($view);?>" />
<?php
if (strpos($s,'invalid') !== false) 
{
?>
    <script>
      top.window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>';
     </script>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

I would suggest re-visiting what your trying to do and tackle it another way as this is not ideal.